# Can I use Shimano Ultegra 6800 BBR60 Bottom Bracket on 105 groupset

Tags: shimano, bottom-bracket

I have currently have a Shimano 105 (5700) 10 speed triple groupset. However the bottom bracket has started clicking and creaking leading to the end of its journey.

Am I able to use this [Ultegra](https://www.merlincycles.com/shimano-ultegra-6800-bbr60-bottom-bracket-62947.html?utm_campaign=googlebase-GB&utm_source=googlebase&utm_medium=shopping&utm_term=Road+Bike+Bottom+Brackets+%26+Cups&ucpo=15190&gclid=CjwKEAiAwfzDBRCRmJe7z_7h8yQSJAC4corOxZRDI112HxQ36RgMFsb4pcrwtxp4lHFWC2Jg6mbwZRoCS2Pw_wcB) as a replacement?

I am not 100% sure but I think my current bottom bracket is this [one](https://www.merlincycles.com/shimano-105-5700-bottom-bracket-49200.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any hollowtech II bottom bracket should be compatible with your crankset. For the frame, you will need to make sure you get the proper thread. Most frames will be BSA thread. Older Italian frames will be Italian thread. If your frame is Italian thread, both bearing cups will thread on clockwise. If it is not, the drive side will thread on counter clockwise. Pay attention to the spacer arrangement on your frame and install the bottom bracket with the same arrangement. Should just be a pretty simple swap.

Comment: Just cheeked my frame on the the ribble [site](http://www.ribblecycles.co.uk/ribble-winter-audax-7005-frameset/) it is English threaded. So should be good to go.

I am tempted to try and just clean the bearings but then saying that the ultegra part I mentioned in my question is on £10 on sale, so might just be worth replacing it for now! 

Thanks for the help.

Comment: you could try blasting it out and regreasing it, bit there are sealed bearings in there that aren't really meant to be disassembled or serviced. and as you've said, it's a pretty cheap part. for the time/effort you are definitely better off replacing it. good luck!